# Dynamically add multiple form controls

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a component which creates a form control with an 'add another field' and 'remove this field' options based on a template object.

For e.g this template:

```
assignmentLinkTemplateObj = {
    name: 'Name',
    url: 'URL'
}
```

should create 2 text fields with field names 'name' and 'url' and placeholders 'Name' and 'URL'. Now the component appends these fields on one click of 'add another assignment'. And removes the combination of these 2 fields upon clicking 'remove this assignment'.

Similarly, if the template is:

```
pastTopicalLinkTemplateObj = {
    name: 'Name',
    type: ['ER', 'MS', 'GT', 'QP'],
    url: 'URL'
}
```

The type is an array, so the component will render a dropdown populated with the values of this array.

This is what I have done:

**Markup:**

```
<form nz-form [formGroup]="validateForm">
  <nz-form-item *ngFor="let control of controlArray; let i = index">
    <nz-form-label [nzXs]="24" [nzSm]="6" *ngIf="i == 0" [nzFor]="control[field]">
        <!-- RENDER DROPDOWNS OR TEXT FIELDS -->
        <ng-container *ngFor="let field of objectKeys(fieldsTemplate)">
            <nz-select *ngFor="let option of fieldsTemplate[field]" *ngIf="isObj(fieldsTemplate[field])">
                <nz-option [nzLabel]="option" [nzValue]="option"></nz-option>
            </nz-select>
            <input 
                *ngIf="!isObj(fieldsTemplate[field])"
                nz-input
                style="margin-right:8px;"
                [placeholder]="fieldsTemplate[field]"
                [attr.id]="control.id"
                [formControlName]="control['id']+control[field]"
            />
        </ng-container>

        <!-- REMOVE FIELD -->
        <i nz-icon type="minus-circle-o" class="dynamic-delete-button" (click)="removeField(control['id'], $event)"></i>
      </div>
    </nz-form-control>
  </nz-form-item>
  <nz-form-item>
    <nz-form-control [nzXs]="{ span: 24, offset: 0 }" [nzSm]="{ span: 20, offset: 6 }">
        <!-- ADD ANOTHER FIELD -->
        <button nz-button nzType="dashed" style="width:inherit;" (click)="addField($event)">
            <i nz-icon type="plus"></i> Add
        </button>
    </nz-form-control>
  </nz-form-item>
</form>
```

**Component.ts:**

```
validateForm: FormGroup;

@Input('name') name;
@Input('fieldsTemplate') fieldsTemplate;
@Input('error_text') error_text;

@Input('controlArray') controlArray: any = [];

@Output('valueAdd') valueAdd = new EventEmitter();
@Output('valueRemove') valueRemove = new EventEmitter();

objectKeys = Object.keys;

keys;

isObj(obj) {
  return typeof obj == 'object';
}

addField(e ? : MouseEvent): void {
  if (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  const id = this.controlArray.length > 0 ? this.controlArray[this.controlArray.length - 1].id + 1 : 0;

  this.keys = Object.keys(this.fieldsTemplate);

  const control = {
    id
  };

  this.keys.forEach(key => {
    control[key] = key;
  });

  const index = this.controlArray.push(control);

  this.keys.forEach(key => {
    this.validateForm.addControl(
      `${id}${this.controlArray[index - 1][key]}`,
      new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    );
  })

  this.valueAdd.emit(this.controlArray);
}

removeField(id, e: MouseEvent): void {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.controlArray.length > 1) {
    const index = this.getControlById(id);
    this.controlArray.splice(index, 1);
    this.keys.forEach(key => {
      this.validateForm.removeControl(`${id}${this.controlArray[index - 1][key]}`);
    });
    this.valueRemove.emit(this.controlArray[index]);
  }
}

getControlById(id) {
  let index;
  this.controlArray.filter((control, i) => {
    if (control.id === id) {
      index = i;
    }
  });
  return index;
}

getFormControl(id: string): AbstractControl {
  return this.validateForm.controls[this.getControlById(id)];
}

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.validateForm = new FormGroup({

  });
}
```

**The problem:**
`this.validateForm.value` now gives me an object something like this:

```
{0name: "asd", 0url: "asd", 1name: "asd1", 1url: "asd2"}
```

Is there any way that I can do this another way and map my form controls to an array of object such that each combination of field is an object and the whole form is an array of these objects.

Comment: Did you try to use `FormArray` inside the `FormGroup`?, then on add just add another `FormGroup` to your `FormArray` and you'll get an array of objects

Comment: Happy to hear!!